# Calculating probabilities for new casino game

Tags: probability, statistics, gambling

I know someone who invented a casino table game. The layout is like hold 'em but it uses cards with letters and suits, etc. Players can play against the dealer or against themselves (like hold 'em), and it has progressives if some remote combination of common cards plus your cards happens to come up.
My question is are there computers that you can just enter the types of cards and the rules, etc and it gives you all the probabilities, or does someone have to figure it all out by hand?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is all pretty vague, but as a general rule:  it's much easier to simulate games of chance than it is to try to compute things analytically.

Comment: Does a simulator exist where you can plug in crazy cards and rules and it can play a million hands?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You will almost certainly need to program a simulator specifically designed around this game.

Comment: My pleasure. I'll try to keep it as manageable as possible. The game has 50 cards... 10 of each of the letters that spell BINGO. A player is dealt 2 cards and there are 5  common cards flopped one at a time... Should I continue or is this question getting out of hand lol

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with you, lulu.

Comment: Before I go, I do have a more tangible example... 4 people are playing the game desribed above, what are the odds of a 5 of a kind showing up?